# Android recycler View and shared preference

Tags: android

I'm making a simple app that uses recyclerView which is populated by data from an online server. The data is displayed in a custom cardview layout which has a favorite button. I am having trouble in implementing the favorite button in recyclerView and the app keeps crashing.

**LogCat**

```
10-03 23:22:06.609  23785-23785/com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer, PID: 23785
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer.newsAdapter.OtherNewsAdapter.checkFavoriteItem(OtherNewsAdapter.java:102)
            at com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer.newsAdapter.OtherNewsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(OtherNewsAdapter.java:64)
            at com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer.newsAdapter.OtherNewsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(OtherNewsAdapter.java:25)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5084)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4385)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4278)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1947)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1359)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1322)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:556)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2673)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2971)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
            at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:581)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2317)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2023)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doT
```

**OtherNewsAdapter.java**

```
public class OtherNewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OtherNewsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Latest> feedItemList;
    private Context mContext;

    SharedPreference sharedPreference;    

    public OtherNewsAdapter(Context context, List<Latest> feedItemList) {
        this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_other_news, null);
        ViewHolder mh = new ViewHolder(v);

        return mh;
    }
    //method to delete
    public void delete(int position){
        feedItemList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);    
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        final Latest feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getArticleImage())
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(viewHolder.thumbnail);

        viewHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getExcerpt()));

        /*If a product exists in shared preferences then set heart_red drawable
         * and set a tag*/
        if (checkFavoriteItem(feedItem)) {
            viewHolder.favImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
            viewHolder.favImage.setTag("red");
            addItem(feedItem);
        } else {
            viewHolder.favImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
            viewHolder.favImage.setTag("grey");
            addItem(feedItem);
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
    }

    View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            OtherNewsRowHolder holder = (OtherNewsRowHolder) view.getTag();
            int position = holder.getPosition();

            Latest feedItem = feedItemList.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, feedItem.getExcerpt(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };    

    public void addItem(Latest lat){
        feedItemList.add(lat);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    /*Checks whether a particular product exists in SharedPreferences*/
    public boolean checkFavoriteItem(Latest checkProduct) {
        boolean check = false;
        List<Latest> favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(mContext);
        if (favorites != null) {
            for (Latest product : favorites) {
                if (product.equals(checkProduct)) {
                    check = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return check;
    }    


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        protected ImageView thumbnail, favImage;
        protected TextView title;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.otherImage);
            this.title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.otherExcerpt);
            this.favImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite);
           favImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String tag = favImage.getTag().toString();
            if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("grey")) {
                sharedPreference.addFavorite(mContext, feedItemList.get(getItemCount()));
                Toast.makeText(mContext,
                        mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.add_favr),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                favImage.setTag("red");
                favImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
            } else {
                sharedPreference.removeFavorite(mContext, feedItemList.get(getItemCount()));
                favImage.setTag("grey");
                favImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
                Toast.makeText(mContext,
                        mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.remove_favr),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }    
        }   
    }
}
```

**SharedPreference.java**

```
 public class SharedPreference {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "NEWS_APP";
    public static final String FAVORITES = "Article_Favorite";

    public SharedPreference() {
        super();
    }
    // This four methods are used for maintaining favorites.
    public void saveFavorites(Context context, List<Latest> favorites) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);

        editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);

        editor.commit();
    }
    public void addFavorite(Context context, Latest product) {
        List<Latest> favorites = getFavorites(context);
        if (favorites == null)
            favorites = new ArrayList<Latest>();
        favorites.add(product);
        saveFavorites(context, favorites);
    }

    public void removeFavorite(Context context, Latest product) {
        ArrayList<Latest> favorites = getFavorites(context);
        if (favorites != null) {
            favorites.remove(product);
            saveFavorites(context, favorites);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Latest> getFavorites(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        List<Latest> favorites;

        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)) {
            String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(FAVORITES, null);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Latest[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites, Latest[].class);

            favorites = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
            favorites = new ArrayList<Latest>(favorites);
        } else
            return null;

        return (ArrayList<Latest>) favorites;
    }
}
```

**SportsFragment.java**

```
public class SportsFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    private List<Latest> feedsList;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private OtherNewsAdapter adapter;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeSports;
    final String url = "http://javatechig.com/?json=get_recent_posts&count=45";
    public static final String TAG = "sports";
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sports_fragment_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.sports);

        swipeSports=(SwipeRefreshLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.swipeSports);
        swipeSports.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        // Initialize recycler view
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler_sports);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.materialProgress);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //Async Task
        // Downloading data from below url

        new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url);
    }

    public void setColorScheme(int colorRes1, int colorRes2, int colorRes3, int colorRes4) {
        swipeSports.setColorScheme(colorRes1, colorRes2, colorRes3, colorRes4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url);
        setColorScheme(R.color.color_scheme_1_1, R.color.color_scheme_1_2,
                R.color.color_scheme_1_3, R.color.color_scheme_1_4);
    }
    public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        //getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
            Integer result = 0;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                // 200 represents HTTP OK
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                    }
                    parseResult(response.toString());
                    result = 1; // Successful
                } else {
                    result = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return result; //"Failed to fetch data!";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // Download complete. Let us update UI
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);



            if (result == 1) {
                if(swipeSports.isRefreshing()){
                    swipeSports.setRefreshing(false);
                }


                adapter = new OtherNewsAdapter(getActivity(), feedsList);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                adapter=null;
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                if(swipeSports.isRefreshing()){
                    swipeSports.setRefreshing(true);
                }
              //error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void parseResult(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("posts");
            feedsList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
                Latest item = new Latest();
                item.setExcerpt(post.optString("title"));
                item.setArticleImage(post.optString("thumbnail"));

                feedsList.add(item);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**row_other_news.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/otherImage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:tint="@color/photo_tint"
            android:contentDescription="@string/country"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/otherExcerpt"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/otherImage"
            android:padding="16dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgbtn_favorite"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/otherExcerpt"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/favorites"
            android:clickable="true"/>    
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot create shared preferences object `SharedPreference sharedPreference`

Comment: so after the list has successfully displayed when clicking the favourite button the app crushes..This is the LogCat                 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            at com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer.newsAdapter.OtherNewsAdapter$ViewHolder.onClick(OtherNewsAdapter.java:134)

Comment: In onClick you should use feedItemList.get (getItemCount ()-1), i don’t know logic of your app,you should check if your list is empty,or if you want index less than size. Index start from 0. Last index is size-1.

Comment: Awesome it works.now when i select the favourites. When scrolling back up the recycler view deselects my favourites. How can i stop the recycler from doing this

Comment: You should add field boolean isFavourite to Latest. When user add to favourite you set to true. In onBindViewHolder you have to check state and set ui.

Comment: Have added public boolean mfavourite and public boolean isFavourite(){
        return mfavourite;
    } to my Latest. How do i implement this in the onBindViewHolder?

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I know this is an old post but this may help some like it did for me

You should add field boolean isFavourite to Latest. When
user add to favourite you set to true. In onBindViewHolder
you have to check state and set ui. – Adam Miśtal

When I came across this it took me a while to really get what he was say and did wht David did and also came to a halt , but then I went back to read nd repeated what Adam said the it hit me

So in Latest add

Private int Id;
In the constructor add
this.id = I'd;

Then add

```
@override
public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
  Latest latest = (Latest) obj;
  If(id != latest.I'd)
     return false;

  return true;
}
```

In the adapter you already have a boolean checkFavoriteItem it will work as is

Now the most important make sure the Data you provide from server each object has an ID as its unique identifier